# implode or explode mysql_fetch_array in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys. 
I'm currently try to make an mysql query than take the results and use them in an another query. So I thought I'm calling my database and use mysql_fetch_array and than implode it do insert `,` so I can use it in an another query. I read here many questions about this and based on the questions i wrote my own piece of code but I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /var/www/html/lager_management/warenkorb.php on line 107

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/html/lager_management/warenkorb.php on line 108
```

Here is the piece of code what is going wrong I can't explain myself and I know `mysql` is old and I should use `myqli`

```
$sql3 = "SELECT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkorb;";
        $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
        while($resultarray3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) 
        {
        $anfrage = array();
        $anfrage = $resultarray3['Index'];
        $anfrage = implode(", ", $anfrage); 

          $sql2 = "SELECT `Index`, `Artikelbezeichnung`, `Status`, `Bestand`, `Lieferant`, `Datum-Einlagerung`, `Lagerort` FROM `lm_Artikel` WHERE `Index` IN (".$anfrage.");";
        }
```

The table lm_Warenkorb looks like this:

```
Index:
    10
    2
    6
```

Comment: Can you show sample data of column `Index` in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do it using one query with nested SELECT:

```
 $sql3 = "
SELECT `Index`, `Artikelbezeichnung`, `Status`, `Bestand`, `Lieferant`, `Datum-Einlagerung`, `Lagerort` 
    FROM `lm_Artikel` 
    WHERE `Index` IN (
      SELECT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkorb
    )";

        $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);

        while($resultarray3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
          // handle the results
        }
```

Comment: Or a simple `JOIN ON lm_Warenkorb.Index=lm_Artikel.Index`

Comment: Thanks worked perfect for me. With this i don't have to use `implode`

Answer (score 0):

you use `mysql_fetch_array($result)` in a while loop, which is perfectly right.

But this obviously will only return one row of your table from database and not the whole column.

therefore `$resultarray3['Index'];` returns the value of Index column of your first table row, which is not an array.

Comment: as long as you use this while loop, it'll return only one index at a time. In fact if you perint the `$resultarray3['Index']` it will print all indexes, but each one after the other. You should fill an array inside the whilr loop and execute the 2nd query afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$anfrage = array();
while($resultarray3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) 
{
 $anfrage[] = $resultarray3['Index'];
}

if(count($anfrage) > 0) {
  $anfrage = implode(",", $anfrage); 
  $sql2 = "SELECT `Index`, `Artikelbezeichnung`, `Status`, `Bestand`, `Lieferant`, `Datum-Einlagerung`, `Lagerort` FROM `lm_Artikel` WHERE `Index` IN (".$anfrage.");";
}
```

Comment: just for a tip, if you are using associative array, use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array

Comment: nope doesn't work it just happens nothing and the second querie is getting an error which says invalid arguments

Comment: index 10 6 2 all three in single row or three different row

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql3 = "SELECT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkorb;";
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
$data = array(0);
while($resultarray3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))
{
    $data[] = $resultarray3['Index'];
}
$sql2 = "SELECT `Index`, `Artikelbezeichnung`, `Status`, `Bestand`, `Lieferant`, `Datum-Einlagerung`, `Lagerort` FROM `lm_Artikel` WHERE `Index` IN (".implode(',', $data).");";
echo $sql2;
```